# Partially select parent node while loading the tree where some childs are checked

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using jstree checkbox having three states - checked, undetermined and unchecked. When I check the parent node child nodes are auto checked. When I select a child node, parent node is partially selected. I have saved checked, undetermined states as 1 and unchecked as 0 in database.

```
$('#btnSubmit').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var checked_ids = [];
    $('.jstree-checked, .jstree-undetermined').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).children('a').attr('id');
        checked_ids.push(id);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        data: { AccessIds: checked_ids },
        success: function () {
            checked_ids.length = 0;
            alert('success!');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Now I want to load the tree in three-state. How can I partially select parent if a child is selected.
I am doing something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.divchkboxtree #divtree').jstree({
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui"]
    })
    .bind('loaded.jstree', function () {
        $('.Node').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.divchkboxtree #divtree').jstree("check_node", '#' + id);
        });
    })
});
```

Here '.Node' class holds the checked ids. Now when I load the tree the problem is all nodes are checked where the parent node is checked as I have saved the partially selected value to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. I maintained it from the back end. I had a field `Object` which is null if it is a parent. So what I did was to extract data which are not parent i.e. I extracted those children whose `IsSelected is 1 i.e. true` and finally the above code worked. No changes on the above code.